# iOS: NSDateFormatter memory leak / viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, nsdateformatter

I've got a view controller that after leaving the stack, shows a memory leak in the Leaks instrument. After reading lots of posts about [the NSDateFormatter bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117263/instruments-leaks-and-nsdateformatter), and implementing the [setDateFormat 'Z' workaround](http://thegothicparty.com/dev/article/nsdateformatter-memory-leak/), I'm still leaking memory (according to Instruments).

In my header:

```
NSDateFormatter *dfm;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter *dfm;
```

In my implementation:

```
@synthesize dfm;
...
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dfm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dfm setDateFormat:@"h:mma Z"]; // leaks with & without this line
}
...
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    //SOLUTION: This method was never being called. Needed to use dealloc, per the answer below.
    [dfm release];
    self.dfm = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Anything stand out as incorrect? The only thing I do with dfm in this class is call `stringFromDate` in a few places to return autoreleased strings that I use with UILabels.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed - so I have learned =).  I've added 'viewDidUnload' the question title so that people might find this post when running into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't rely on `viewDidUnload` to be called. You also need:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.dfm = nil;
    // whatever else you need
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You only need to `self.dfm = nil` because the default synthesized setter will do the release.

Comment: I just tried adding that, though it didn't fix the leak. I'm already setting `self.dfm = nil` in my viewDidUnload, so isn't calling it again in dealloc redundant? thx for the quick response though. EDIT: missed your first line =).  Unfortunately, it still leaks...

Comment: Ah! After cleaning my project in XCode and doing more tests, this was indeed the issue: viewDidUnload was not being called. Many Thanks.