# NSDateFormatter Memory Leak Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've read this post: ([NSDateFormatter leak question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117263/instruments-leaks-and-nsdateformatter)) which states that NSDateFormatter leaks when the Z is used in the date/time.  My date format happens to be as follows: 2011-08-15T22:58:24-07:00

Yet for some reason it's also telling me that NSDate is leaking.  Here's the code that's in my init method:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[self setCreatedAt:[formatter dateFromString:hCreatedAt]];
[formatter release];
```

Any ideas on a workaround to this?  It would be much appreciated!  Just an FYI .. this is ISO 8601 format.  I could possibly switch the format if necessary.  If that's required, please suggest the proper date/time format I should use.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with this code. Unless `setCreatedAt:` is poorly behaved, the best I can suggest is to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: It looks like maybe `hCreatedAt` might be the problem. Are you sure you are releasing any memory you allocated for that?

Comment: It appears that if you don't use [formatter setDateFormat:] and [formatter setLocale:] the memory will leak.  Really strange, however after those two it appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being that I had to use

```
[formatter setDateFormat:] //and
[formatter setLocale:]
```

In order to avoid the memory leak.